# Which pattern is implemented in Django Middleware? (Chain of responsibility or Decorator)

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-middleware, chain-of-responsibility, decorator

I'm trying to figure out what pattern is used in Django Middleware. Maybe there is combination of patterns?

Comment: Can you describe the design, for those of us unfamiliar with Django Middleware?